# Decrypting a byte[] back to String without loss of data

Tags: java, security, encryption, cryptography

I have written a small application to encrypt and decrypt Strings using AES.  Here is the code:

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;

public class AesEncryptionTest {
    static IvParameterSpec initialisationVector = generateInitialisationVector();
    static SecretKey encryptionKey = generateKey();
    static String plainText = "test text 123\0\0\0";

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Initial Plain Text = " + plainText);

            byte[] encryptedText = encrypt(plainText, encryptionKey);
            System.out.println("Encrypted Text     = " + encryptedText);

            String decryptedText = decrypt(encryptedText, encryptionKey);
            System.out.println("Decrypted Text     = " + decryptedText);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static byte[] encrypt(String plainText, SecretKey encryptionKey) throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding", "SunJCE");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, encryptionKey, initialisationVector);
        return cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    }

    public static String decrypt(byte[] encryptedText, SecretKey encryptionKey) throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding", "SunJCE");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, encryptionKey, initialisationVector);
        return new String(cipher.doFinal(encryptedText),"UTF-8");
    }

    public static SecretKey generateKey() {
        SecretKey secretKey = null;
        try {
            KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
            keyGenerator.init(128);
            secretKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
           // Whine a little
        }
        return secretKey;
    }

    public static IvParameterSpec generateInitialisationVector() {
        byte[] initVector = new byte[16];
        SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
        secureRandom.nextBytes(initVector);

        return new IvParameterSpec(initVector);
   }
}
```

Output:

```
Initial Plain Text = test text 123
Encrypted Text     = [B@407dcb32
Decrypted Text     = test text 123
```

My main areas of concern are around encrypting into a byte array and decrypting back to a String.  I know that this can introduce unexpected behaviour and loss of data.  While this has not been observed in my testing, could anyone suggest any changes that would help combat this?  I ***think*** I have this covered by ensuring UTF-8 is used both ways.

If anyone see's any other red flags with my code and how I have done this, I'm open to criticism/suggestions.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're calling `toString()` on a `byte[]` which is never a good idea. Basically it's not giving you any useful information.

If you want to convert arbitrary binary data into a string, I'd suggest using hex or base64, both of which are covered elsewhere. There's no indication that you've actually lost any information here in the encryption/decryption - the problem is your display of the encrypted data. So long as you *don't* try to treat that as simple encoded text data (because it isn't) you should be fine. In particular, your code is already specifying UTF-8 as the conversion from the original text to unencrypted binary data, and vice versa - so that's safe.

If you don't need to convert the byte array to a string, it's simplest to avoid doing so in the first place. (For example, you could write it to a file still in the binary form very simply, then load it back into a byte array later.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  Unfortunately I have to have a representation of the encoded text data, its a (bad) design that has to stay I'm told, and a hash isn't strong enough.  Certain Strings need to be encoded and stored for use later, then they need decoded further down the line.  I don't really see the need for it at all, but hey.  Would it be a useful to encode the raw byte[] data again to hex/base64 and store this representation, rather than the raw binary data, or will this just shift the problem?

Comment: You *have* a representation of the encoded text data: it's the byte array. You could use base64 to convert that to a string if you wanted to, but you must *not* just call `toString` on the byte array.

Answer (score 2):

You asked for other red flags, so I'll give you a few pointers regarding the crypto:

1. Generally you don't have to provide the provider name when you use an algorithm name. Specifying the provider makes your code less portable.
2. It is better to use a standardized padding mode such as `"/PKCS5Padding"` (identical to PKCS#7 padding in Java). If you want to use the current padding mode you can configure the Bouncy Castle provider and specify `"/ZeroBytePadding"`. This padding mode does not work correctly for plaintext that ends with zero valued bytes.
3. You store the IV in the same class variable as the key. I know this is just test code, but normally the IV need to be send or established at both sides. The most common way to use the same key at both sides is to prefix the IV to the ciphertext.
4. The size of the IV depends on the cipher. It is always 16 for AES, but you may want to make the IV size configurable or use the `Cipher.getBlockSize()` method.
5. Use GCM mode (available since 1.8) encryption if you also want authenticity/integrity and protection against padding oracle attacks.
6. You should use a fresh, random IV for each encrypt, instead of generating an IV just once.

Comment: GCM is only available since Java 8 unfortunately. And a static IV is a red flag.

Comment: Thanks for these, great points.  I have added all of these to my code (with the exception of point 5).  I moved generation of the IV into only the `encrypt()` method only, and keep it as being passed as an additional param in the `ciper.init()` method.  Then I retrieve it in the `decrypt()` method using `cipher.getParameters()`.  @ntoskrnl, does this change fix the red flag?

Comment: Thanks @ntoskrnl, I'll change that to 1.8. Where is the static IV? The `generateInitialisationVector()` method looks random enough to me...

Comment: @owlstead Fair enough, this is probably just a test. The main issue is IV reuse. Make sure the same IV is not used for more than one encryption operation in the production environment.

Comment: @ntoskrnl Ah, yes, now I see, it's random much like [number 4](http://xkcd.com/221/), I did not even notice that :)

Answer (score 1):

the way to make sure the conversion is without loss is to use the same Charset when converting back and forth as you do.

Creating a string of the encrypted data is however not safe for further use; it can contain any and all sequences of bytes and might not fit into whatever Charset you originally used (you're not making this error, just pointing it out).

You're also printing the hashcode of the byte[] mid way in the code, not the individual bytes.

Comment: Good answer, but I think the first paragraph is redundant/incorrect or at best confusing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  Ah, I didn't realise that it was a hashcode of the byte[] I was displaying.  Thanks for pointing that out.